# Given a value of k, is it possible to express explicitly the collection of x satisfying Fib(x)=k

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Fibonacci_numbers), the formula to extend to all real the Fibonacci number is:
$$
\text{Fib}(x)=\frac{\varphi^x - \cos(\pi x)\varphi^{-x}}{\sqrt 5}
$$
Given a value of k, is it possible to express explicitly the collection of x satisfying Fib(x)=k ?

Comment: In other words , you ask whether this function is injective , right ?

Comment: Thanks Peter. I know this function is not injective (considering all R); I'm interested in finding all possible values of x starting from Fib(x). For example. through wolframalpha, I tried to find the values of x when Fib(x)=40 getting: -11.37...; -10.67..; etc.

Comment: "The formula..." That is one formula.

Comment: Given your last comment, suggest question changed to "Given a value of k, is it possible to express explicitly the collection of x satisfying Fib(x)=k ?"

Comment: @ClaudioMartines Another possible extension mentioned in this [large post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/589841/interpolated-fibonacci-numbers-real-or-complex?rq=1) is the ordinary binet formula. It’s inverse has a closed form, including all branches, as a [Fox H function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoxH.html). Would you like this answer?

Answer (score 0):

$\def\Fib{\operatorname{Fib}}$

We apply [Lagrange reversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_reversion_theorem#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20Lagrange%20reversion,of%20compositions%20with%20such%20functions.&text=Then%20for%20any%20function%20g%2C%20for%20small%20enough%20y%3A&text=In%20which%20case%20the%20equation%20can%20be%20derived%20using%20perturbation%20theory) to invert $\Fib(x)$, like Wolfram repository’s [inverse Fibonacci](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/InverseFibonacci/). It may be possible to get more branches by substituting $\phi x=\ln(w)+2\pi ik,k\in\Bbb Z$ or solving for $x=\cdots$ and using the [complex logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm), but that is more complicated, so $k=0$:

$$\Fib(\log_\phi(w)))=a\iff w=\sqrt 5a+\frac12w^{-\frac{\pi i}{\ln(\phi)}-1}+\frac12w^{\frac{\pi i }{\ln(\phi)}-1}\implies \Fib^{-1}(x)=\log_\phi\left(\sqrt5x+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{2^nn!}\left.\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}\left(x^{-\frac{\pi i}{\ln(\phi)}-1}+x^{\frac{\pi i }{\ln(\phi)}-1}\right)^n \right|_{\sqrt5x}\right)$$

Next use the binomial theorem:

$$\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}\left(x^{-\frac{\pi i}{\ln(\phi)}-1}+x^{\frac{\pi i }{\ln(\phi)}-1}\right)^n=\sum_{m=0}^n\binom nm \frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}x^{\frac{\pi i (2m-n)}{\ln(\phi)}-n}$$

which makes [factorial power $n^{(m)}$](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FactorialPower.html) appear. Therefore:

$$\bbox[3px,border: 2px solid lightgreen]{\Fib^{-1}(x)=\log_\phi\left(\sqrt 5x+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^n\left(\frac{\pi i (2m-n)}{\ln(\phi)}-n\right)^{(n-1)}\binom nm\frac{(\sqrt5x)^{\frac{\pi i (2m-n)}{\ln(\phi)}-2n+1}}{2^nn!}\right)}$$

[shown here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Fib%28Log%28goldenratio%2C3.7+sqrt%285%29%2BSum%5BSum%5B%281%2F2%29%5En%2Fn%21+binom%28n%2Cm%29+%283.7+%E2%88%9A5%29%5E%281+-+2+n+%2B+%28i+%282+m+-+n%29+%CF%80%29%2Flog%28goldenratio%29%29+factorialpower%28%28-n+%2B%28i+%282+m-+n%29+%CF%80%29%2Flog%28goldenratio%29%29%2C+-1+%2B+n%29%2C%7Bm%2C0%2C9%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C9%7D%5D%29%29). The result is a [double hypergeometric series](http://elib.mi.sanu.ac.rs/files/journals/publ/29/29.pdf)

Comment: Truncating the sum at $n=0$ and taking the round function of it gives the inverse for $x\in\Bbb N$, the sum gets more accurate as $x\in\Bbb C,|x|\to\infty$, and a similar approach can be done to invert the [Fibonacci polynomial](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FibonacciPolynomial.html) $F_v(a)$ wrt $v$

Comment: Thank you Tyma !

Answer (score 0):

In the real domain, if you want to find the zero of function

$$f(x)=\frac{\phi^x - \cos(\pi x)\,\phi^{-x}}{\sqrt 5}-k$$ you can have an explicit expression performing one single iteration of any Newton-like method starting with
$$x_0=\frac{\log \left(\sqrt{5} k\right)}{\log (\phi )}$$

Since $$f'(x)=\frac{\pi  \phi ^{-x} \sin (\pi  x)+\text{csch}^{-1}(2) \phi
   ^x+\text{csch}^{-1}(2) \phi ^{-x} \cos (\pi  x)}{\sqrt{5}}$$ the formula for Newton method is simple but it does not make any problem for Halley or Householder methods.

Trying for a few values of $k$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
k & \text{Newton method} &\text{Halley method} &\text{solution} \\
 2 & 2.99666272790 & 2.99939552636 &  3.00000000000 \\
 3 & 4.00093541961 & 3.99997677784 &  4.00000000000 \\
 4 & 4.54911525254 & 4.54911256276 &  4.54911255651 \\
 5 & 5.00004596343 & 4.99999973617 &  5.00000000000 \\
 6 & 5.39185329558 & 5.39184960448 &  5.39184960691 \\
 7 & 5.72146999558 & 5.72146173169 &  5.72146173497 \\
 8 & 6.00001134392 & 5.99999998654 &  6.00000000000 \\
 9 & 6.24201126307 & 6.24200781881 &  6.24200782135 \\
 10 & 6.45779718802 & 6.45779711744 &  6.45779711745 \\
 11 & 6.65371448777 & 6.65371391099 &  6.65371391090 \\
 12 & 6.83362397630 & 6.83362256091 &  6.83362256070 \\
 13 & 7.00000138968 & 7.00000000012 &  7.00000000000 \\
 14 & 7.15458943766 & 7.15458861266 &  7.15458861262 \\
 15 & 7.29874744351 & 7.29874715848 &  7.29874715847 \\
 16 & 7.43362013074 & 7.43362010332 &  7.43362010332 \\
 17 & 7.56020990738 & 7.56020988947 &  7.56020988947 \\
 18 & 7.67940477808 & 7.67940466250 &  7.67940466251 \\
 19 & 7.79198976833 & 7.79198956259 &  7.79198956261 \\
 20 & 7.89865435506 & 7.89865411580 &  7.89865411582 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thank you Claude for your answer, very useful.